# Dynamic reversing z-index with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a customer's requirement that there by 10 divs, like chapters in a book.  Each chapter will have a thumbcut (see [here](http://www.rossgage.com/thumb-cut-description.html) for clarification) on the side that will allow the reader to switch directly to that chapter.  (I don't need page turning animations - yet... shhhh!).

Each chapter will have the thumbcut display on the right or left side of the page, depending on which chapter is currently open.  The first chapter will only have the thumbcut on the left, the last only on the right.  Each of the other chapters will have to have their thumbcut moved depending on where it is in the stacking order.  I'm not asking about the thumbcut right/left determination in this question.

I am considering using z-index to determine which chapter is "open", ie. on top.  If each div were given an array index of 0-9, and the z-index were to correspond with the chapter's array index, that would be a good static start.  However, is gets tricky when you have middle pages open, because the previous chapters would have progressive (0, 1,...) z-index numbering, while the following chapters would continue the numbers, in declining order from the currently-open chapter, (x, x-1, x-2,...).

This is necessary since each chapter's thumbcut must be visible to the reader, regardless of where the reader is in the chapter order.

Any ideas on how to best implement this?  Javascript is necessary, since it's a dynamic function determined after page load.  Is z-index the best route?

NOTE:  This is a Rails app, running TurboLinks, so it needs to be responsive to AJAX and static assets.

EDIT: The pages are initially fanned out on the right side of the view, with the first page on top and the rest offset to the right by 10px.  This gives the illusion of a "fan" or the pages of a book.  As page 2-9 come to the top, the lower-numbered pages are now off to the left.  Assuming I use a standard `<div class="chapter">` and then give each individual div a unique id, offsetting them from each other and assigning a z-index.

The problem I run into is that if all the s are offset to the right of the previous, creating the leafing effect, and they are all the same width, as I bring each one to the top of the order, say `z-index = 100`, it completely covers all of the left-hand side divs except the first one.

Take 5 business cards and fan them out with the fan on the right side.  Then take the 3rd card and bring it to the top, but in the same relative horizontal position.  It completely covers the 2nd card, since the 2nd card isn't showing from underneath the 1st on the left hand side and is now covered on the right side by card #3.

Comment: Give all the closed pages their normal, array index. Then give the open page a very high z-index so it goes above the rest.

Comment: I don’t really see what the problem is here … If those ”thumb cuts” are supposed to be displayed at the side, then I don’t see how this is much different from say what any regular “tab” plugin could do. A static example showing how it is supposed to look when one of the middle “pages” is open would help perhaps.

Comment: @Barmar - That won't work since the open page would cover up either the left or right side.  That's why subsequent chapters have a decreasing index vs increasing in the previous.

Comment: @CBroe - A tab won't work, since the thumbcut needs to display on the left side if the open chapter comes after it.  See the self-example I explain in the edit.

Comment: It would help if you could make a demonstration page that shows what you're trying to achieve, with a stack snippet or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I just add panels sequentially in the DOM in order of **last** to **first** (bottom to top). You could then use position:absolute or position:fixed to make them overlap relative to their container or the screen, respectively.

That way, if you want to inject a page between, you can just add it between children rather than keeping track of a Z Index that would be between the two values (which means you need to reserve in-between values and deal with the possibility that you'll run out, etc.).

Comment: I don't need to inject a page, just show the current page on top with the thumbcuts on the right or left, depending on the current page.  The number of pages will be constant.